# Twig/Timber operator is not working for me in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, twig, wordpress-theming, timber

I have `productprice` and `salestax` set as a variable and but have am having a real issue getting this operator to work properly `{{ productprice * 0.salestax }}` to work with twig/timber in WordPress it does not calculate anything at all?

However this works fine with no problems at all `{{ productprice * 0.06 }}` and doing a dump of `{{ dump(salestax) }}` = string '06' (length=2)

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I think it has something to do the output of '06' but not sure how to deal with that, just learning yet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your dump shows `salestax` return `string` - it is **NOT** countable - no math can be applied. Also it cannot be concatenate in this way - twig uses `~` for concatentation.

In order to work first you need to do is convert string value into integer. You can do it on PHP side and twig templates

**PHP:**
I personally recommend this way as your logic will be applied on back-end part of application.

```
// *.php

// Get Timber context
$ctx = Timber::context();

$productPrice = 1000; // it is integer
$salesTax = '06'; // it is a string as you would get it now (from post meta or whatever)

// set new variable
$salesPrice = $productPrice * ( 1 - (int) $salesTax / 100 ); // (int) string will return integer - so math is works

//pass it to context
$ctx['salesprice'] = $salesPrice;

// Render twig
Timber::render( 'view.twig', $ctx );
```

now in your twig file you can acces it (it should return 940 in my example)

```
{{ salesprice }}
```

**TWIG:**
But if you wish to handle logic in twig you can convert string with [number_format](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/number_format.html) filter

```
{{ productprice * ( 1 - salestax|number_format / 100 ) }}
```

Comment: Thanks so much!!! This here did exactly what I was looking for 
`{{ productprice * ( salestax|number_format / 100 ) }}`